# Read file lines into shell line separated by space

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a file called requirements.txt, each line has a package :

```
package1
package2
package3
```

I'm looking for a command that will take each line of requirements.txt and join them in one line, space separated.

So basically, I'm looking to generate the following command:

```
command package1 package2 package3
```

I tried using a for and applying `command` for each line of `requirements.txt` but it was much slower

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use `bash` redirection and command substitution to get the file contents as arguments to your command:

```
command $(<file)
```

This works because not only space is a valid word splitting character, but newline as well – you don’t need to substitute anything. However, in the case of *many* lines you will get an error referring to the shell’s `ARG_MAX` limit (as you will with substitution solutions). Use `printf` to built a list of arguments and `xargs` to built command lines from it to work around that:

```
printf "%s\0" $(<file) | xargs -0 command
```

Note that neither of these approaches work for lines containing whitespace 
or globbing characters (besides the newline of course) – fortunately package names don’t (AFAIK). If you have whitespace or globbing characters in the lines use either `xargs` (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168037/507051)) or `parallel` (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168381/507051)).

Comment: @EliahKagan See the last paragraph, yes – OP asks specifically about a list of package names, where this is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and sorry about my confusing initial comment. In hindsight, I should likely have edited this instead of commenting. You might mention `xargs command < requirements.txt` as an alternative to your second command. I believe that covers the practical cases where someone might prefer your second command over the command in steeldriver's answer (for example, if people want to strip away leading and trailing whitespace or allow multiple names per line, treated as such). I think that makes sense here... but it could be its own answer, so once again I find myself reluctant to edit.

Comment: @EliahKagan Wow, you’re really decent. Mentioning the `xargs`-only approach in any other way than by linking to the other answer feels like stealing to me – I used `xargs` just to work around overlong command lines, this does not change the potential word splitting and globbing problems. `parallel` however makes for an own answer without any doubt, I hope I have the time to write one today.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `xargs`, with the delimiter set to newline (`\n`): this will ensure the arguments get passed correctly even if they contain whitespace:

```
xargs -rd'\n' command < requirements.txt
```

From [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xargs.1.html):

> **`-r`, `--no-run-if-empty`**
>   If the standard input does not contain any  nonblanks,  do  not  run  the  command. Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.  This option is a GNU extension.
>
> **`--delimiter=delim`, `-d delim`**
>   Input items are terminated by the specified character.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. `xargs` is perfect for this. Also, this is the only solution posted so far that doesn't perform unintended [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion).

Comment: @EliahKagan This may not work as expected if your inputs are long - please see ` xargs --show-limits`

Answer (score 3):

Use `tr` and bash substitution:

```
command $(tr '\n' ' ' < requirements.txt)
```

for example:

```
echo $(tr '\n' ' ' < requirements.txt)
```

output would be:

```
package1 package2 package3
```

or:

```
sudo apt install -y $(tr '\n' ' ' < requirements.txt)
```

would install all packages.

Comment: That is outputting "package3xe" to me

Comment: What is the output of `file requirements.txt`?

Comment: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators (This file was created in windows and sent to docker)

Comment: Run `sudo apt install dos2unix` then `dos2unix requirements.txt` to remove `\r` (carriage returns) from your file it has been created on a windows machine I guess. or try `$(tr '\r\n' '  ')` instead.

Comment: Figured it out, it worked with '\n\r' , thanks for the hint

Comment: with the default `IFS`, the `tr` is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for this (`sudo apt install parallel`):

```
parallel -m command <file     # or
parallel -m command :::: file
```

`parallel` takes only newline as the delimiting character and (of course) doesn’t perform any globbing, so characters like space, asterisk`*`, question mark `?` and the like in the lines are no problem at all. `-m` is for `m`ultiple arguments like `xargs` does it. If you don’t want command lines to be run in parallel, which is what `parallel` does by default, add `-j1` for `1` `j`ob at a time – for package installation this may be advisable.

#### Example run

```bsh
$ ls
a_test  file
$ cat file
a*
b with spaces
$ parallel -m 'printf "line: %s\n"' <file
line: a*
line: b with spaces
$ parallel 'printf "line {#}: %s\n" {}' <file
line 1: a*
line 2: b with spaces
```

The directory contains two files: `a_test` and `file`. `file`’s content consists of two lines: `a*` and `b with spaces`. The third command line in this example executes `printf "line: %s\n"` with all the lines from `file` as its arguments, this prints the argument with “line: ” before and a linebreak after it. As there is no globbing, the first argument `a*` can’t match the existing file `a_test`, but is printed as-is. The same goes for the next argument with spaces in it, the spaces are preserved instead of the argument being split into three.

The fourth command is just an addendum showing one of the many nice features of `parallel`: `{#}` in a command is replaced by the sequence number of the job, and as this one calls `printf` with only one argument (no `-m`) it is equal to the current line number. `{}` is the placeholder for the argument(s) and can be omitted if there’s no other placeholder used in the command and the argument(s) should be added to the end of the command, which I did before.

#### Further reading on GNU `parallel`:

- [Homepage](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)
- [Youtube playlist of tutorial videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1)
- [`man parallel`’s exhaustive example section](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/parallel.1.html#example:%20working%20as%20xargs%20-n1.%20argument%20appending)

Answer (score 2):

Read items from file instead of standard input:

```bash
xargs --arg-file=requirements.txt echo
```

Or, to fail if the argument list is too long (rather than running `echo` more than once):

```bash
xargs --arg-file=requirements.txt -n 1 echo
```

The short form for `--arg-file` is `-a`, so you can use `xargs -a requirements.txt` in place of `--arg-file=requirements.txt` if you want.

Comment: Note that this fails on lines with spaces: “xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (…) or newlines (…).”

Comment: you can add delimiter:  xargs -a requirements.txt -d '\n' echo

Answer (score 1):

Just read the lines into an array. This is easy with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) 4 (which provides the [readarray](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray) command):

```
readarray -t lines < /path/to/file
echo "${lines[@]}"
```